# detect a red object in my world

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
i'm trying to make my robot rotating until he "see" a red object and then drive to this object.
i tried to do it with point cloud library ,i understand i need to subscribe to  a certain topic but i don't know which one?
also after subscribing i don't know how to isolate the color of the frame from the message just received, can someone please help me?
i'm using ros indigo with armadillo model.
Thx.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250690/detect-a-red-object-in-my-world/) by [iguma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28886/iguma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using a depth camera then the PCL library would be appropriate, but if it is a regular color camera then you would want to use OpenCV, and could try out colored blob detection like in https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/ (it mentions the blobcolor doesn't work as of that blog post, but I see in http://answers.opencv.org/question/26295/simpleblobdetection-set-blobcolor-python/ that it was fixed which may be available in your version).  Or try out `inRange` to get a binary image of just the places in the image that are red ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218280/thresholding-rgb-image-in-opencv ) and do some other operations to your object.

You should use http://answers.opencv.org for OpenCV specific questions.

If there is a single topic with a name that ends in `image_raw` or `image_color` then that might be the topic to subscribe to- use rqt_image_view to select from available image topics and find the right one if there are several options.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0